# How to sort through a 2d for loop and input results into hypotenuse formula

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to iterate through a list of coordinates and determine their distance to the origin `(0,0)`. For example, the array of pairs `[[1,3],[-2,2]]` should yield `3.162` and `2.828` respectively as result.

I created a 2 dimensional for loop to extract each coordinate. I then called a `calcHypotenuse()` function to square the numbers and add them in order to get distances.

However, when I push the results of each hypotenuse and return them I get mixed result. I'm getting `4.52` and `2.82`. For some reason, `2.82` is the correct output for the second coordinate pair, but the first coordinate pair is not.

NOTE: Please dismiss `k`. It has not pertinent relevance to the problem of finding the distance to the origin.

```js
function kClosest(points, k) {
    let length = [];
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            a = points[i][j] * points[i][j];
            b = points[i][j + 1] * points[i][j + 1];
            console.log('Squared Cordinates: (' + a + ',' + b + ')')
            length.push(parseFloat(calcHypotenuse(a / 2, b / 2).toFixed(4)))
            break;
        }
    }

    function calcHypotenuse(a, b) {
        return (Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b)));
    }
    return length;
}



console.log(kClosest([
    [1, 3],
    [-2, 2]
], K = 1));
```

This problem is derived from Leet Code: https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/

Comment: When you divide by 2 use decimal form: `2.0` and learn about integer arithmetic.The second time you have **even** coordinates - that's why it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add in the description that this is Javascript. Either way, when I added the '.0', nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring `k` as you say, you can easily get distances to origin `(0,0)` using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
function calcHypotenuse(a, b)
{
    let hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2));
    return Number.parseFloat(hyp.toFixed(4));
}

function getDistancesTo(points, pair)
{
    let [x0, y0] = pair;
    return points.map(([x, y]) => calcHypotenuse(x - x0,y - y0));
}

console.log(getDistancesTo([[1, 3], [-2, 2]], [0, 0]));
```

I'm also using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to say that an element of the array is a pair `[x,y]`. But maybe you will understand it better this way:

```
function getDistances(points, pair)
{
    let x0 = pair[0], y0 = pair[1];
    return points.map(p => calcHypotenuse(p[0] - x0, p[1] - y0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't quite gotten to studying .map yet as I am a newish JS developer. Would you mind describing how that works in this example?

Comment: @TylerMorales I have updated to a generalized version. So you can calculate distance to a particular point and added some explanation. Let me know if you need some more clarification...

Answer (score 1):

You're squaring the coordinates and then dividing the result by 2 before putting it into the hypotenuse function. Furthermore, you don't need a double for loop in this case since you're iterating through each subarray/pair once. What I would suggest doing is just have one loop that iterates through each pair, and put each pair of coordinates into the hypotenuse function like so,

```
function kClosest(points, k) {
    let length = [];
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        a = points[i][0];
        b = points[i][1];
        length.push(parseFloat(calcHypotenuse(a, b).toFixed(4)))
    }

    function calcHypotenuse(a, b) {
        return (Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b)));
    }
    return length;
}
```